# Temperature of black body without photon

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

Can the temperature of a black body be defined without using radiation? Energy spectrum of black body is a function of temperature so when we say a given blackbody is at temperature $T$ we measure the energy of radiation (ultimately photons) to assign $T$ using following kind of graph [image]

In other words, is it possible to operationally define the temperature of a black body without going through the route of detecting photons?

Comment: You can measure body temperature using a lot [of different technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_measurement#Technologies), just choose some.

Answer (score 2):

Temperature is defined thermodynamically as the energy change as the entropy changes: $$T=\left( \frac{dU}{dS}\right)_{P,V},$$ entirely independently of radiation. To operationally measure a temperature of a body without measuring photons you will have to use a thermometer or something similar.